# Does yuidoc work with coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, yui

Has anyone ever setup yuidoc to work with coffeescript? Here's my yuidoc.json file:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "description": "App",
  "version": "1",
  "url": "http://example.com",
  "options": {
    "paths": [
      "./"
             ],
   "exclude": "vendor",
   "syntaxtype": "coffee",
   "extension": ".coffee",
   "outdir": "./api_docs"
  }
}
```

When I run `yuidoc -c yuidoc.json .` the example classes I made show up in the api.js file and the the html pages are generated but nothing shows up under "Classes" when I go to the url generated by `yuidoc --server`.

**Update**

Here are my comments.

```
###*
# Description
#
# @project MyProject
# @author Me
# @class MyClass
###
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yuidocjs after V0.3.19 support parse coffee comment syntax（0.3.19以后的版本已经支持CoffeeScript）see [here](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/pull/56)

Add CoffeeScript comment syntax support.

```
set options --syntaxtype coffee.

$ yuidoc --syntaxtype coffee -e .coffee input
```

Thi is CoffeeScript's code:

```
###*
# The test project
# @project tester
# @title The Tester
# @icon http://a.img
# @url http://one.url
# @url http://two.url
# @author admo
# @contributor davglass
# @contributor entropy
###
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for the help. When I put: `file:://path/to/index.html` all of the classes etc show up.  If I do `yuidoc --server -c yuidoc.json` none of the classes show.  Got any ideas as to what could be going on? Thanks!

Comment: What's this "以后的版本已经支持"?

Comment: after version support == 以后的版本已经支持

Answer (score 2):

yuidoc doesn't look at your code but at the comments that start with /** and contain the proper keywords.  You can create API docs from a file containing no code at all, just suitable comments and, conversely, you will get no docs out of plain code with no comments, as is your case.

Comment: I updated my question to show the comments I had in my code.  According to [this](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/pull/56) coffeescript comments should work.